# Not sure how to implement methods for Sorted List Java

Tags: java, sortedlist

EDIT 3: In short, what I'm asking is how can I fix the code I've written to do what the instructions for the assignment is asking(below each of the 4 blocks of code). I'm not sure what needs to be fixed to make it do what the instructions says.

I'm trying to figure out how to implement a few methods for an assignment I'm doing, but I can't seem to figure it out. The code below is what I have so far.

The first method is:

```
public boolean contains(int ID)
{
    // TODO: implement this method
    PersonNode current = m_first;
    PersonNode previous = null;
    if(current == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    while(current != null)
    {
        if(current.getID() == ID)
        {
           return true;
           //previous = current;
           //current = current.getLink();
        }
        previous = current;
        current = current.getLink();
    }

    return false; // replace this statement with your own return
}
```

This is what I have so far and I'm not sure if that's how it's supposed to be.
Instructions from assignment: This method takes an ID and checks whether a PersonNode associated with the given ID is in the list. If so, return true, otherwise, return false.

The second method is:

```
public PersonNode get(int ID)
{
            // TODO: implement this method
    PersonNode current = m_first;
    PersonNode previous = null;
    if(current == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    while(current != null)
    {
        if(current.getID() == ID)
        {
           return current.getLink();
           //previous = current;
           //current = current.getLink();
        }
        previous = current;
        current = current.getLink();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Instructions for this method: This method takes an ID and checks whether a PersonNode associated with the given ID is in the list. If so, return the reference to the node, otherwise, return null.

The third method is:

```
public boolean add(int ID, String name)
{
    // TODO: implement this method
    PersonNode newNode = new PersonNode(ID, name);
    PersonNode current = m_first;
    PersonNode previous = null;
    if(m_first == null)
    {
        m_first = newNode;
        m_numElements++;
        return true;
    }

    while(current != null)
    {
        if(current.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(previous.getName()) < 
        previous.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(current.getName())) //not sure, fix
        {
           previous = current;
           current = current.getLink();
        }
        else
        {
           break; //might be return false;
        }
    }
    if(previous == null)
    {
        newNode.setLink(m_first);
        m_first = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        newNode.setLink(current);
        previous.setLink(newNode);
    }

    return false; // replace this statement with your own return
}
```

The instructions for this method is:  This method takes an ID and a name and adds a PersonNode with these values into the list.  The list must still be sorted in ascending order by ID numbers. If add is successful, return true. If the node already exists in the list, return false.

The last method is:

```
public boolean remove(int ID)
{
    // TODO: implement this method
    PersonNode current = m_first;
    PersonNode previous = null;
    boolean found = false;

    while(current != null)
    {
        if(current.getID() < ID)
        {
           previous = current;
           current = current.getLink();
        }
        else if(current.getID() == ID)
        {
           found = true;
           current = current.getLink();

           if(previous == null)
           {
              m_first = current;
           }
           else
           {
              previous.setLink(current);
           }
        }
        else
        {
           return found;
        }
    }

    return false; // replace this statement with your own return
}
```

The instructions for this method: This method takes an ID and remove a PersonNode associated with the given ID from the list. If remove is successful, return true. If no such node exists, return false.

So that's what I have so far and I'm not sure if I'm on the right track or if I'm totally off.

Summary of what I need help with:

-Help implementing the methods. You don't have to give the code(I'd prefer if you don't, but the choice is yours), but if you do, keep it simple so I won't have to ask about it. I just need some guidance. Any help would be appreciated.

Additional info:

-Not allowed to implement additional methods or create variables that exist outside of those four methods.

-There's a PersonNode class and a Test Class(not posting the code for this since it's long, but if the methods are implemented correctly, it will work.)
Code for the PersonNode class:

```
public class PersonNode
{
private int m_ID;
private String m_name;
private PersonNode m_link;

public PersonNode(int ID, String name)
{
    m_ID = ID;
    m_name = name;
    m_link = null; 
}

public void setID(int ID)
{
    m_ID = ID;
}

public int getID()
{
    return m_ID;
}

public String getName()
{
    return m_name;
}

public void setName(String name)
{
    m_name = name;
}

public void setLink(PersonNode link)
{
    m_link = link;
}

public PersonNode getLink()
{ 
    return m_link;  
}
```

}

If you can find other questions on SO that might help, feel free to link, but make sure you read my post first, don't just link anything related to sorted lists. I already tried looking, but the ones I found were not that helpful for my case.

If anything is not clear, I'll edit to make clearer. Sorry if the post is really long.

Edit: What I'm asking is how can I make the methods do what the instructions I posted below each one says. I'm not quite sure if my code is close to the instructions or not. The output gives incorrect results, most likely due to the implementation being incorrect.

EDIT 2: Updated contains() and get() with my new code. It's working a little more smoothly than before, but could still use some improvement. Also, add() and remove() still need work. Just look at the paragraph after each block of code for what I need help with. I'll be checking frequently, so feel free to lend a hand.

Comment: When you run your code, what does it do differently than what you would want it to do? Currently you just posted a code dump and asked: "Is this ok?" That's not how SO works. If you want to ask a question about your code, give the premises: "I want to do X, my code here <snippet> does Y, what's wrong?"

Comment: Ah sorry. I'll edit my post. What I'm asking is how can I make the methods do what the instructions I posted below each one says. I'm not quite sure if my code is close to the instructions or not. The output gives incorrect results, most likely due to the implementation being incorrect.

Comment: I still feel that you're asking a "fix all the issues in my code please" kind of question, which may take multiple iterations to get everything sorted. Asking for help isn't a problem, just that asking lots of different things in one question makes the question really hard to answer sufficiently and thoroughly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in your `get()` function, you need to return the PersonNode where the ID is match. So you should `return current` instead of `return current.getLink()`, which `current.getLink()` seems the next node of the linked list.

---

Second, your `add()` function seems not doing right. Since your list should always be sorted, you can iterate it from head until you find the ID is greater than input ID, that's the position you should insert your `newNode`.

```
PersonNode newNode = new PersonNode(ID, name);
PersonNode currentNode = mFirst;

for(; currentNode.getLink().getID() < ID; currentNode = currentNode.getLink());
newNode.setLink(currentNode.getLink());
currentNode.setLink(newNode);
```

However, you should consider some conditions which may cause this code fail:

#### The list is empty

If the list is empty, your mFirst will be null. Therefore, when you call `currentNode.getLink()` it will cause a NullPointerException. So you should add some check on it.

```
// insert when list is empty
if (mFirst == null) {
    mFirst = newNode;
    return true;
}
```

#### Insert at first position

If your new ID is smaller than all elements in the list, it will cause the code insert at the second position, not the first position. So you can add a test before get into the loop.

```
if (mFirst.getID() > ID) {
    // insert at front
    newNode.setLink(mFirst);
    mFirst = newNode;
}
```

#### Insert at the last position

If your new ID is greater than all elements in the list, then your for loop will encounter a NullPointerException. When your `currentNode` is the last element in your list, `currentNode.getLink()` will return null, and at next step when you call `currentNode.getLink()` it will cause the exception. Therefore, you need to check this in the for loop (I replace it with a while loop).

```
while(true) {
    if (currentNode.getID() == ID) {
        // ID exists
        return false;
    }

    PersonNode nextNode = currentNode.getLink();
    if (nextNode == null) {
        // insert at last
        currentNode.setLink(newNode);
        return true;
    }
    if (nextNode.getID() > ID) {
        // insert at mid
        newNode.setLink(nextNode);
        currentNode.setLink(newNode);
        return true;
    }

    currentNode = nextNode;
}
```

So finally, your `add()` function will looks like:

```
PersonNode newNode = new PersonNode(ID, name);
PersonNode currentNode = mFirst;

// insert when list is empty
if (mFirst == null) {
    mFirst = newNode;
    return true;
}

if (mFirst.getID() > ID) {
    // insert at front
    newNode.setLink(mFirst);
    mFirst = newNode;
}

while(true) {
    if (currentNode.getID() == ID) {
        // ID exists
        return false;
    }

    PersonNode nextNode = currentNode.getLink();
    if (nextNode == null) {
        // insert at last
        currentNode.setLink(newNode);
        return true;
    }
    if (nextNode.getID() > ID) {
        // insert at mid
        newNode.setLink(nextNode);
        currentNode.setLink(newNode);
        return true;
    }

    currentNode = nextNode;
}
```

---

Third, is your `remove()` function. Just go through the list and search for the specific ID. If found, **link previous node to next node**. It's very similar to the `add()` function.

```
// remove when the list is empty
if (mFirst == null) {
    return false;
}

// remove at first
if (mFirst.getID() == ID) {
    mFirst = mFirst.getLink();
    return true;
}

PersonNode currentNode = mFirst,getLink();
PersonNode previousNode = mFirst;
while(true) {
    if (currentNode == null) {
        // ID not found
        return false;
    }

    if (currentNode.getID() == ID) {
        previouseNode.setLink(currentNode.getLinke());
        return true;
    }

    currentNode = currentNode.getLink();
}
```

---

When implementing the LinkedList structure, remember to consider the conditions that may make your code fail and **beware of the order of the instructions**.

Answer (score 0):

I think your while loop is not end ,and other problem i don't find.

```
while(current != null)
{
    if(current.getID() == ID)
    {
       return true;
    }
}//how the while out?
```

Comment: Yeah. That's in my contains(). I'm not sure what to put there, so I just left it as return true;

Comment: @williamh how about to and this :  current = getLink()  in the after of if

Comment: It fixed the contains() a little, but I think something else is needed or one of the other methods is wrong.